# Get DataValueField of DayPilot in Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010, daypilot-scheduler

I am using daypilot schedular in my asp.net application. how can i get the value of DataValuefield in Code behind.

```
 <DayPilot:DayPilotScheduler ID="DayPilotScheduler1" runat="server" 
    DataStartField="start" 
    DataEndField="end" 
    DataIdField = "AppId"
    DataTextField="name" 
    DataValueField="id" 
    ViewType="Gantt"
    >
</DayPilot:DayPilotScheduler>
```

I tried e.Value but it is getting `DataIdField`. How to get `DataValueField` ?

```
Protected Sub DayPilotScheduler1_EventMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventMoveEventArgs)

Dim id as string = e.Value  //gets DataIdField


End Sub
```

Comment: What's not working your `Event` or the `e.Value` statement? Does your `DayPilotScheduler1_EventMove` get fired on change? If no  I think You should add `EventMoveHandling="PostBack"` to fire your event on postback.

Comment: Event fires and e.Value contains "AppId". I need to get "id" too

Answer (score 0):

As seen on this [link](http://www.daypilot.org/api/pro/latest/html/P_DayPilot_Web_Ui_DayPilotCalendar_DataValueField.htm) the `DataValueField` is obsolete:

> Gets or sets the name of the column that contains the id (primary key). Obsolete. Use .DataIdField instead.

In my project I can access the value this way:

```
DataValueField="id" //column "id" of my source table
```

Get it in `BeforeEventRender`:

`string id = (string)e.DataItem["id"];`